# How to reorder Elements based on corresponding elements' order in Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

So far I accomplished to give every link a class name and its corresponding div an id with the same value as the class.

So it looks like this:

```
<a class="content1">Content1</a>
<a class="content2">Content2</a>
<a class="content3">Content3</a>
```

and the divs, while not in order at least carry the responding ids:

```
<div id="content2">Content1</div>   
<div id="content1">Content1</div>
<div id="content3">Content1</div>
```

The question is how can I reorder the divs so they are ordered the same way like the links?

I can not use substring or something like that, as the IDs could be anything, even without numbers.

Comment: I find it very difficult to understand your question

Comment: I want to reorder the divs based on their id. But the id could be anything. I always have as many divs as I have links. The divs should be in the same order as the links.

Comment: Not hard, but are the divs actually siblings? Or do they have separate parents?

Comment: they appear one after another in the source, as in the code

Comment: @user1721135 are u using the class name on anchor only for the hook up with div? then there is another option...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:-

This uses starts with selector so be aware of it.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DEjhw/)

```
$('a[class^=content]').each(function(){
   var div = $('#'+this.className);
    div.parent().append(div);
});
```

If you are using the classNames only to hook up with div's i have another approach using `data-*`, which probably will be more cleaner, if className is only used in the anchor for hookup. using `data-target`.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j6yUd/)

```
<a  data-target="#content1">Content1</a>
<a  data-target="#content2">Content2</a>
<a  data-target="#content3">Content3</a>
<div id="content2">Content2</div>   
<div id="content1">Content1</div>
<div id="content3">Content3</div>
```

#

```
$('a[data-target^=#content]').each(function(){
   var div = $($(this).data('target'));
    div.parent().append(div);
});
```

Comment: also using them for other things, and setting them with jquery too, so I guess i rather stick with the classes, first solution worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all divs are located within div.container (for example)

```
//iterate through all links
$('a').each(functioh() {
  //get div block which id is link's className
  var $divBlock = $('div.' + $(this).attr('class'));
  //add div to the container
  $('div.container').append($divBlock);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with giving the anchors some `href` attributes, instead of classes. It should look like

```
<a href="#content1" class="contentlink">Content1</a>
<a href="#content2" class="contentlink">Content2</a>
<a href="#content3" class="contentlink">Content3</a>
```

Now you can easily iterate them, find the respective divs and reorder them:

```
var previous;
$("a.contentlink").each(function() {
    var selector = $(this).attr("href");
    var div = $(selector);
    previous = previous ? div.insertAfter(previous) : div;
});
```

[Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/RhLPA/)